# Jenkins CI - Run SSH Deployment on Multiple servers

Tags: jenkins, ssh, publish

I feel it's a little crazy I couldn't find anything along these lines, especially as it's an incredibly simple requirement: Is there a way you can deploy from Jenkins using SSH/SCP, yet write only one instance of a transfer-set/exec script?

As it stands, deploying to servers is kind of **INSANE** in that I need to create a new "Deploy to SSH" task, choose a different server from the drop down and then copy/past all transfer-sets and execs from the previous entry. Then do it again. And again. And again.

There must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This may not be a short-term immediate solution for your question---**
(On long run this can be used)

Your requirement seems to me like you need a configuration management equipment. You could use Chef, Puppet or Ansible. And automation of this deployment can be done using Jenkins CI.

One example of how to deploy an application on jboss using Ansible -

## Deploy a hello world application

- jboss: src=/tmp/hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war deployment=hello.war state=present

Of course, this will require installation of Ansible and little bit of initial configuration. Ansible is simplest of all deployment mechanisms.

Check this for more details - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro.html

Comment: We currently use Puppet and Foreman to orchestrate and manage our environments. Part of the CI process is deploying the package to servers, it seems a bit overkill to wire some kind of mechanism between puppet and jenkins so that deployments can happen on demand from the CI system.

I guess I just fundamentally disagree that puppet is the correct tool to use in this scenario. I would like to avoid introducing other config management tools into the workflow, and Jenkins has an entire 'Publish to..." interface which would be a little pointless if it was really not intended for this purpose.